# NSFetchRequest GroupBy an attribute of to-many relationship

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchrequest

[image]

I have been persisting some records in core data.
 Records have to-many relationship.
searching the persist data by to-many relationship seems to be simple and I used "SUBQUERY" to achieve it. I am facing problem with grouping records.

I need to group "ZCMORecord" by stringValue of "ZCMORecordValue"

Since  "ZCMORecordValue" is a to-many relationship.

I even need to group ZCMORecords with one or more "ZCMORecordValue".

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context= [[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate ]managedObjectContext];

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *valueDesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"ZCMORecord" inManagedObjectContext:context];    

[fetchRequest setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
[fetchRequest setFetchLimit:PAGE_SIZE];

NSPropertyDescription *recordRelationShip = [fetchRequest.entity.relationshipsByName objectForKey:@"recordValueSet.stringValue"];

[fetchRequest setPropertiesToGroupBy:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:recordRelationShip,nil]];
NSError *error;
id fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

Getting errors when I try this.

> SELECT clauses in queries with GROUP BY components can only contain
>   properties named in the GROUP BY or aggregate functions

I need to fetch records in group. 
I could't figure out what to set in "setPropertiesToGroupBy:" and "setHavingPredicate:" to achieve proper results.

OKAY!! Example of how I Store my data

```
ZCMORecordValues


id    stringValue<NSString>  dateValue<NSDate>     record


name     Alex                     -            record1<ZCMORecord>

DOB      -                     10/10/1990      record1<ZCMORecord>

name     Anto                     -            record2<ZCMORecord>

DOB      -                     05/05/1990      record2<ZCMORecord>

name     Max                     -            record3<ZCMORecord>

DOB      -                     10/10/1990      record3<ZCMORecord>

name     Mary                     -            record4<ZCMORecord>

DOB      -                     01/01/1990      record4<ZCMORecord>
```

Now I want to group my "ZCMORecord"  with with respect to DOB.

Any suggestion on changing the model to facilitate grouping is also welcome

Comment: How do you image grouping by multiple things to work? You need to show an example of what result you're looking for and I'm guessing you'll need to do it after the fetch (or add other info to the model to facilitate)

Comment: @Wain lets say I group by one thing. How can I make it work. How do i set havingPredicate and propertiesToGroupBy? I cant do after fetch, because I have huge amount of records.

Comment: That one thing would be on the entity itself, not an entity at the end of a to-many relationship

Comment: So group by to-many relationship is not done :s.

OKAY!! for grouping by multiple things , I edited my question.

How can I do it. @Wain

Comment: just specify those property names in the group by array (your question no longer relates to your managed object model so it's hard to say anything specific now)

Comment: @Wain sorry for the confusion I changed my question for clarity please have a look at at and suggest a sollution

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to use a `NSFetchedResultsController`, fetch the record values and pass the `stringValue` as the `sectionNameKeyPath`.

Comment: I need to groupBy both dateValve and stringValue at the same time

Comment: You can do the first via the fetched results controller, the second in memory. It would also help if you could explain your use case - I have my doubts that this is reasonable.

Comment: I changed my question for better understanding. Please suggest a way i can group it via fetched results controller @Mundi

Comment: I cant give stringValue or dateValue  in the  sectionNameKeyPath because it take those empty entries also. (All i want it how do I specify the entities "only" to be considered for grouping)